# POST request to application

Tags: spring-mvc, post, facebook-ads-api

I send async requests to facebook. Each of those requests has field "notofication uri". 
When async jobs are all done, this URI will be used to notify the caller with POST action and the id of the object.

I've wrote spring action in controller to obtain that id:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.POST
public void asyncRequestSet(@RequestBody String body, 
  @RequestParam("offer_id") Long offerId, 
  @RequestParam("user_id") Long userId) {

    logger.info("{}", body); 
}
```

Example callback url: http://example.com/callback?user_id=1&offer_id=1

But the body of request is:

```
--------------------------9c15923bd5bc01ce

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="async_request_set_id"

5011222203926
--------------------------9c15923bd5bc01ce--
```

How could I get id "5011222203926" without using regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to explictely obtain post data in Spring MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494774/how-to-explictely-obtain-post-data-in-spring-mvc)